# Remove array objects contained in another array by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have to remove all the objects from array that contain the same id present in another array.

This code works

```
myArray = [{id: 1, value: 'a'}, {id: 2, value: 'b'}, {id: 3, value: 'c'}];
itemsToRemove = [{id: 2, value: 'x'}, {id: 3, value: 'y'}];
for (const item of itemsToRemove) {
    myArray.splice(myArray.findIndex(a => a.id === item.id), 1);
}
```

but I'm looking for a more elegant way to do it. I've tried also

```
const newArray = myArray.filter(a => itemsToRemove.findIndex(i => i.id === a.id));
```

but doesn't works. (it creates a new array, but at least one item with the same id remains in the new array).

Is there a clean and concise way to do it?

Comment: Well, the problem with findIndex inside of filter, is that things that are "not found" by findIndex return -1, which is truthy for filter, and if the first item contains the found index, you get 0, which is falsy for filter.  If you change it to find instead of findIndex, should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but as [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535480/james) said in the comments, `findIndex` is the wrong choice because it returns `-1` when the item is not found. `filter` requires its predicate to return a `boolean` and `-1` is not a `boolean`, so it's coerced to one. Unfortunately, `-1` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) which doesn't match your intention in the predicate.

You can add a comparison to check that `findIndex` returned a value less than zero, or you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const myArray = [{id: 1, value: 'a'}, {id: 2, value: 'b'}, {id: 3, value: 'c'}];
const itemsToRemove = [{id: 2, value: 'x'}, {id: 3, value: 'y'}];

const newArray1 = myArray.filter(a => itemsToRemove.findIndex(i => i.id === a.id) < 0);
console.log(newArray1);

const newArray2 = myArray.filter(a => !itemsToRemove.find(i => i.id === a.id));
console.log(newArray2);

const newArray3 = myArray.filter(a => !itemsToRemove.some(i => i.id === a.id));
console.log(newArray3);
```

---

It's worth noting that [`find` isn't supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#browser_compatibility), [nor is `findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#browser_compatibility). [`some` is supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#browser_compatibility), so it's the most compatible.

`some` is also the most performant:

[image: JSBench.me screenshot showing the results in the table below]

| Test | Result | Operations/second |
| --- | --- | --- |
| findIndex | 10.63% slower | 26632285 |
| find | 12.39% slower | 26107649 |
| some | fastest | 29799972 |

Comment: Thanks. I solved it using the find function as suggested by you and James. I had to use !find though, because find returned an array with only the values ​​I should have dropped.